# Zenity progress bar and output

Tags: bash, zenity

I wrote this little script:

```
response=$(process ...) | zenity --progress --pulsate
echo $response
```

I want read the response of the process, whatever it is, and show a pulsating progress bar in the meanwhile. The problem is that I don't read any response at the end. I think because all the output from the previous process is sent to zenity.

Comment: Um, no, this is wrong. You assign something to the variable `$response` and then pipe *this assignment* to zenity.

Comment: Yes, I know was wrong. Unfortunately I didn't know the command "tee"... I'm going to try it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, no, this is wrong. You assign something to the variable `$response` and then pipe *this assignment* to zenity. Try

```
process | tee /tmp/response.txt | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close
response=$( cat /tmp/response.txt )
```

That way, the output will be stored in the file `/tmp/response.txt`, which you can later read into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and didn't want to create a temp file, so my solution was:

```
#!/bin/bash
FIFO=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $FIFO
(cat $FIFO | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close) &

response=$(process)

echo 'Bye bye' > $FIFO
rm -f $FIFO
```

Comment: mktemp same as creating temp file.. so I don't know whether you mean manually create one replaced with mktemp perhaps?

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto 'mktemp -u' just generates a unique filename and doesn't create a file. It's then used to create the fifo.

Comment: Seems I don't check the -u flags, I apologize. Thank you for the correction. It's dry run, so it doesn't create any file. I see