# yad progress bar with terminal output

Tags: 12.04, dialog

I'm trying to develop an application in **`bash`** which can display the terminal logs progress on the yad (Yet Another Dialog) dialog. You can consider it just like **windows installation**, where it displays all the files that are been installed **just below the progress bar**. I have referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316280/zenity-progress-bar-and-output) post for my work but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm running the installation script as root user.

I'm trying this from past few days but couldn't get success. I tried to save the log in a text file and than copy it back to the dialog, but the process dint work out. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code in `bash` with screenshot of the output.

```sh
yad --form --seperator='\n' --columns=2 --quoted-output \
--field="$MSP:FBTN" "bash -c sersoft"  # from here I call the function sersoft

sersoft()
{
    some_funct

    if [ "$ret_val" == 3 ] || [ "$ret_val" == 4 ]; then
            krel=$(uname -r | cut -b 1-10)
            ufw disable
            apt-get update -y
            apt-get upgrade -y
            apt-get -y install gcc g++ libpcap0.8-dev build-essential

            # few more apt-get's and finally

            apt-get -y update
            apt-get -y upgrade

    elif [ "$ret_val" == 5 ]; then
            systemctl stop firewalld
            systemctl disable firewalld
            yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

            # few more yum installs's and finally

            yum -y update
            yum -y upgrade
    fi      | tee response.txt | yad --progress --pulsate --auto-close
            response=$( cat response.txt )
}
export -f sersoft
```

[image: Progress Log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
${command} |
while read -r line; do echo "# ${line}"; done |
yad ${config} --title="${title}"
```

---

With error handling:

```
#! /bin/bash
#  (GPL3+) Alberto Salvia Novella (es20490446e.wordpress.com)


mainFunction () {
    title="${1}"
    command="${2}"
    log="/tmp/$(date +%s)"
    config="--progress --pulsate --center --no-buttons --auto-close --progress-text='Working...' --width=800"

    ${command} 2> "${log}" |
    while read -r line; do echo "# ${line}"; done |
    yad ${config} --title="${title}"

    checkErrorLog "${log}"
}


checkErrorLog () {
    log="${1}"
    error=$(cat "${log}")
    rm "${log}"

    if [ "${error}" != "" ]; then
        echo "${error}" >&2
        errorWindow "${error}"
        exit 1
    fi
}


errorWindow () {
    error="${1}"
    config="--center --button=OK:1"

    yad ${config} --title="Error" --text="${error}"
}


mainFunction "Ping" "ping google.com -c5"
```